# how to use Node.JS foreach function with Event listerner

Tags: node.js, for-loop, event-listener

I am not sure where I am going wrong but I think that the event listener is getting invoked multiple times and parsing the files multiple times.

I have five files in the directory and they are getting parsed. However the pdf file with array 0 gets parsed once and the next one twice and third one three times.

I want the each file in the directory to be parsed once and create a text file by extracting the data from pdf.

The Idea is to parse the pdf get the content as text and convert the text in to json in a specific format.

To make it simple, the plan is to complete one task first then use the output from the below code to perform the next task.

Hope anyone can help and point out where i am going wrong and explain a bit about my mistake so i understand it. (new to the JS and Node)

Regards,
Jai

Using the module from here:
https://github.com/modesty/pdf2json

```
  var fs = require('fs')
    PDFParser = require('C:/Users/Administrator/node_modules/pdf2json/PDFParser')
    var pdfParser = new PDFParser(this, 1)

    fs.readdir('C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/Project/Input/',function(err,pdffiles){
      //console.log(pdffiles) 
      pdffiles.forEach(function(pdffile){
         console.log(pdffile)
         pdfParser.once("pdfParser_dataReady",function(){
           fs.writeFile('C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/Project/Jsonoutput/'+pdffile, pdfParser.getRawTextContent())    
           pdfParser.loadPDF('C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/Project/Input/'+pdffile)
         })
      })        
    })
```

Comment: The code you have there looks correct to me. I tried looking up the documentation for `pdfParser.once` but couldn't find it. I am having a suspicion that it probably has something to do with the `.once` api.

Comment: Hi Samuel, thanks for the input. If I remove the .once and use .on to check when event listener is on then the files get parsed multiple times I.e over 20 times each so in text file I get something like this name: testtestetstetsttesttesttest instead of just once like name:test.

Comment: Possibly a bug for the parser module you are using. If performance is not a concern you might want to consider doing it the synchronous way for now and see if it work. If you are interested in how to synchronously control the async calls, I can chip in a few ideas as solution.

Comment: It be great if you can suggest some ideas..I am new to node and js

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment, just contributing 'work-around' ideas for OP to temporary resolve this issue.

Assuming performance is not an issue then you should be able to asynchronously parse the pdf files in a sequential matter. That is, only parse the next file when the first one is done.

Unfortunately I have never used the npm module `PDFParser` before so it is really difficult for me to try the code below. Pardon me as it may require some minor tweaks to make it to work, syntactically they should be fine as they were written using an IDE.

**Example:**

```
var fs = require('fs');
PDFParser = require('C:/Users/Administrator/node_modules/pdf2json/PDFParser');

var parseFile = function(files, done) {
    var pdfFile = files.pop();

    if (pdfFile) {
        var pdfParser = new PDFParser();
        pdfParser.on("pdfParser_dataError", errData => { return done(errData); });
        pdfParser.on("pdfParser_dataReady", pdfData => {
            fs.writeFile("'C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/Project/Jsonoutput/" + pdfFile, JSON.stringify(pdfData));
            parseFile(files, done);
        });
        pdfParser.loadPDF('C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/Project/Input/' + pdfFile);
    }
    else {
       return done(null, "All pdf files parsed.")
    }
};

fs.readdir('C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/Project/Input/',function(err,pdffiles){
   parseFile(pdffiles, (err, message) => {
       if (err) { console.error(err.parseError); }
       else { console.log(message); }
   })
});
```

In the code above, I have isolated out the parsing logic into a separated function called `parseFile`. In this function it first checks to see if there are still files to process or not, if none then it invokes the callback function `done` otherwise it will do an `array.pop` operation to get the next file in queue and starts parsing it.

When parsing is done then it recursively call the `parseFile` function until the last file is parsed.